# update multiple array elements matching a query in mongodb

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I am using python code for updating multiple elements in an array that matches a query. Here is my document structure:

```
    doc: {
    "userId":327238,
    "assessmentId":115513,
    "institutionId":1632,
    "subjects":[
        {"Id":238,"Included":false,"Rank":1},
        {"Id":239,"Included":true,"Rank":4},
        {"Id":240,"Included":false,"Rank":1},
        {"Id":241,"Included":true,"Rank":10}
     ]
   }
```

I would like to set 'Rank':0 only for array elements with 'Included':false. I have tried the below code but it sets 'Rank':0 for all the array elements.

```
 query = {"assessmentId":115513, "institutionId":1632, "subjects":{"$elemMatch":{"Included":false}}}
 update = {"$set":{"subjects.$[].Rank":0}}
 db.test.update_many(query, update)
```

Any help would be appreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do with the positional operator + arrayFilters as follow:

mongo shell:

```
db.test.updateMany( {"doc.assessmentId":115513, "doc.institutionId":1632 } ,{"$set":{"doc.subjects.$[fs].Rank":0}},{arrayFilters:[{"fs.Included":false} ]}  )
```

python:

```
query={"doc.assessmentId":115513, "doc.institutionId":1632 }
update={"$set":{"doc.subjects.$[fs].Rank":0}}
db.test.update_many( query ,update,array_filters=[{"fs.Included":False} ]  )
```

explained:
You define variable fs.Included:false  in the arrayFilter that will be used to match the array objects  in the update $set stage , and only the matched array objects will have the Rank set to 0

Comment: I am getting an error with the above query -     raise TypeError("%s must be True or False" % (option,))
TypeError: upsert must be True or False

Comment: tested directly in mongo shell is working , for the pymongo driver may differ abit , can you add exactly what you run in python and what python version + pymongo driver you use ?

Comment: python version - 3.8.3, pymongo verison - 3.10.1

Comment: this is the command i'm running in python script -  query = {"assessmentId":115513, "institutionId":1632, "subjects":{"$elemMatch":{"Included":False}}}
 update = {"$set":{"subjects.$[].Rank":0}}
 db.test.update_many(query, update)

Comment: i've change the command to this after your suggestion -                     db.test.update_many({"assessmentId":115513, "institutionId":1632}, {"$set":{"subjects.$[fs].Rank":0}}, {'arrayFilters':[{"fs.Included":False}]})

Comment: also what is your monogdb version , arrayFilters are supported in >=mongod 3.6

Comment: also in python the arrayFilters are given as follow: array_filters=[..]